# How to register containers using networkMode=host automatically in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, elastic-load-balancer

For performance reasons, we need to use docker networkMode=host in ECS. Under this setting, is it possible to have ECS manage registration/de-registration of container against the ALB/ELB? If not what are some of the typical options use to manage this process?

Answer (score 0):

No! in my experiences it was not possible to have ALB and network mode host and dynamic ports.  I'm trying to find documentation that specifies it, but I found out by trying to create a service with networkmode = "host", and a dynamic port (`0` ) with an ALB and received a cloudformation error on creation.

My use case was that statsd is running bound to ec2 machine, and I was hoping to be able to deploy ALB service in neworkMode host so it would be easy to reference statsd from the container using `localhost`.

To get around this with the ALB and bridge networking each ECS container instance has a configuration file put on it with it's IP so the container can avoid having to hit the metadata API to get the ECS container instance IP.